# Prove that $O(\sum_{i=0}^{h}{2^i\times(h-i)}) \sim O(2^h)$

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

I want to prove that, $$\sum_{i=0}^{h}{2^i\times(h-i)} \sim O(2^h).$$

---

I did come up with the below proof,
$$\sum_{i=0}^{h}{2^i\times(h-i)} \sim O(\sum_{i=0}^{h-1}2^{h-1}) \sim O(h2^h),$$
but as it is clear I did not find the correct path for my proof.

Comment: You can split it into two summations, one will be a GP series and the other will be AGP.

Comment: This is a "non-proof" as you give no justification for the first equivalence. In addition, the second equivalence disproves the claim, while being... wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$S_h:=\sum_{i=0}^{h}{2^i(h-i)}.$$

We have

$$S_h-S_{h-1}=\sum_{i=0}^{h}{2^i(h-i)}-\sum_{i=0}^{h-1}{2^i(h-1-i)}=\sum_{i=0}^{h-1}{2^i}=2^{h}-1.$$

So by induction,

$$S_h=S_0+\sum_{i=1}^h(2^i-1)=2^{h+1}-h-2.$$

Comment: There is a little mistake in the last line. By induction, $S_h = S_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{h}{(2^{h-i} - 1)}$. It's also good to hint that $S_0 = 0$.

Comment: @AshkanKhademian: why $2^{h-i}$ ??

Comment: let's do some of the steps. $S_h = S_{h-1} + 2^h - 1 = S_{h-2} + 2^{h-1} - 1 + 2^h - 1$; and in case of induction we'll have $S_h=S_0 + \sum_{i=0}^{h-1}(2^{h-i} - 1)$. As it is obvious, the power is decrementing in each step. However I myself made a slight mistake in the first comment. You could also say $S_h=S_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{h}(2^{i} - 1)$ for more readability.

Comment: @AshkanKhademian: oops, $2^h$ was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots+x^n=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}.$$
Differentiate from two sides:
$$1+2x+3x^2+\dots+nx^{n-1}=\frac{(n (x-1)-1) x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}.$$
Multiply two sides by $x$:
$$x+2x^2+3x^3+\dots+nx^{n}=\frac{(n (x-1)-1) x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2}.$$

Plug $x=2$ into into formula you will get:

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^h2^i(h-i)&=\sum_{i=1}^h h2^i-\sum_{i=1}^hi2^i\\
&=h(2^{h+1}-1)-((h-1)2^{h+1}+2)\\
&=h2^{h+1}-h2^{h+1}+2^{h+1}-3-h\\
&=O(2^h).
\end{align}$$